# How is it correct to check in unittest that the method response is not empty?

Tags: tkinter

I wrote an application - a simple game where the user writes his question and gets one of the answers that randomly get from the list. Now we need to make a test that would check the function of random answers: we compare her answer and make a conclusion about whether it is empty or not (it is important to check: the answer is not empty).

I have not encountered testing, even with a simple version of it. What's wrong with me?

```
import random
import tkinter as tk

RESPONSES = ['Yes', 'No']

class QuestionsAnswers(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, main):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, main)
        self.main = main
        
        # let's create a frame where there will be a field for user questions
        self.frame_question_answer = tk.Frame(master=self.main)                                

        # let's create a frame that forms an area with answers to the user's questions
        self.frame_answer = tk.Frame(master=self.main)

      # let's add a Text widget - an area for writing questions
        self.text_box_question = tk.Text(self.frame_question_answer)
        
        # widget for displaying random answers
        self.text_box_answer = tk.Text(master=self.frame_answer)
            
        # let's create an element of the Ask button 
        self.button_ask = tk.Button(master=self.frame_question_answer,
            text='Ask')
        
        # creating a Clear button element 
        self.button_clear = tk.Button(master=self.frame_question_answer,
            text='Clear')
 
        # bind all widgets to the grid
        self.frame_question_answer.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=1, sticky='e')                       
        self.frame_answer.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan = 1,sticky='w')
        self.text_box_question.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news')         
        self.text_box_answer.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news')
        self.button_ask.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='ew')
        self.button_clear.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky='ew')

        # binding the event processing to the button
        self.button_ask.bind('<Button>', self.questionQuery)
        # we bind the command to the button for clearing the question and answer fields
        self.button_clear.bind('<Button>', self.clearText)

     # The handler of the user's question
    def questionQuery(self, event):
        question = self.text_box_question.get('1.0', tk.END) # reading the text from the widget 
        self.main.update_idletasks() 
        self.main.after(2000, lambda: self.button_ask.configure(text='Ask')) 
        if not question.strip():
            self.text_box_answer.insert(tk.END, 'Ask your question\n') 
        else:
            self.answerQuery()               
                    
        # Random response return function
    def answerQuery(self):
        time.sleep(2)
        self.text_box_answer.insert(tk.END, 'Hmm...' + '\n') # output to the widget
        self.main.update_idletasks()
        time.sleep(2)
        self.text_box_answer.insert(tk.END, 'I look beyond the twists of fate' + '\n')
        self.main.update_idletasks()
        self.main.after(2000, lambda: self.text_box_answer.insert(tk.END, random.choice(RESPONSES) + '\n'))
        
    # the function of clearing the question and answer fields 
    def clearText(self, event):
        time.sleep(1)
        self.text_box_question.delete('1.0','end')
        time.sleep(1)
        self.text_box_answer.delete('1.0', tk.END)
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    window = tk.Tk()
    quest_answer = QuestionsAnswers(window)
    window.update()
    window.mainloop()
```

Next, I write the test code:

```
import unittest
class TKinterTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.questionsAnswers = QuestionsAnswers()

    def test_answerQuery(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.questionsAnswers.answerQuery(), len(self.questionsAnswers.answerQuery())!=0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The test was passed, but it gave an error, although it should not be. Why is that?

Comment: Your `answerQuery()` function never returns anything, so it will always be `None`.

Comment: That's not so. The function gives a random response. The app is working

Comment: It literally doesn't return anything. There is no `return` statement.

Comment: Yes, but the function writes answers to the application itself. It returns responses to the application, not the code

Comment: Yes, but your test is checking what it _returns_, not what it _does_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider this line of your test code:

```
self.assertEqual(self.questionsAnswers.answerQuery(), len(self.questionsAnswers.answerQuery())!=0)
```

You are asserting on what `answerQuery` returns. Since the function has no `return` statement, it's returning `None`. Your assertion is functionally identical to `assertEqual(None, len(None)!= 0)`.

Instead, you need to be asserting on the side effects of the function. Since the function is ultimately adding text to a text widget, you need to assert on the contents of the text widget.  It might look something like this:

```
actual = self.text_box_answer.get("1.0", "end-1c")
self.assertEqual(actual, "whatever you expect it to be")
```

Since the title of the question is how to test that the response is not empty, you can just assert on the length of the result:

```
self.assert(len(actual) > 0)
```

... or the more pythonic:

```
self.assert(actual)
```

Comment: thanks! I am concerned about the question: what can I expect when the function selects answers randomly? For example, I will tell the test that I am waiting for A answer, but in reality, as a result of a random selection, answer B will be transmitted to the text widget, and the test will not converge

Comment: Given the unknown result of the choice of answers, I'm trying to build a test on the fact that there is an answer (no matter which one is available)

Comment: for some reason I get a syntax error with a pointer to self.assert. How true will the following verification code be: `actual = self.test_box_answer.get("1.0", "eng-1c")
self.assertisnotnone(actual)`